# Magento 2 : Module is disabled, shows in disabled list, but the functionality in admin remains

Tags: magento2, module, cache, uninstall-module

I have a module that I disabled that adds background patterns to individual product pages. We want to remove the functionality. So I ran the CLI command to disable the module. I listed the modules in the CLI and it shows up now in the list of disabled modules. I did the setup:upgrade command. Then I cleared caches. It's functionality still shows in the admin.

**List of commands run after disabling:**

```
magento setup:upgrade
magento cache:clean
magento cache:flush
magento indexer:reindex

rm -rf generated/code/*
rm -rf generated/metadata/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/composer_home/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

A rather vigorous clearing of caches. It still shows up in the admin on product edit pages with the fields to fill in.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have also tried putting it in developer mode. This is all being done locally.

Comment: What's the name of the module?

Answer (score 0):

> If the module is related to product edit page than
>
> You need to remove attribute/Field from the attribute set

Go to **Store > attributes > Atttibute set >** open perticular attribute set and **drag and drop** the module's **field/attribute**  to **unassigned attributes**

Comment: Is this for Magento 2? Sorry, I am new to Magento 2 and just trying to figure out what is going on with this project and I am not seeing this path in the admin. Still poking around to see if it got moved somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this link in  Add than run Uninstall Script**

File: app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Uninstall.php

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html